Bootstrapping to a Certain Length - R
Let's say that I have three distributions of data: 'x', 'y', 'z.' There is x (n = 2000), y (n = 3000), and z (n = 4000).
I require the length of these distributions to be equal, let's say: n = 10000.
Can someone show me a function that allows me to transform x, y, z, into bootstrapped samples with n = 10000, please?
Would be appreciated
x <- rnorm(n = 2000, mean = 0, sd = 1)
y <- rnorm(n = 3000, mean = 0, sd = 1)
z <- rnorm(n = 10000, mean = 0, sd = 1)


If you want to resample with replacement you could do: x1 <- sample(x, 10000, replace = TRUE); y1 <- sample(y, 10000, replace = TRUE); z1 <- sample(z1, 10000, replace = TRUE)

@AllanCameron's answer is correct, but assumes that x, y and z are uncorrelated.  That's obviously partially true, because their lengths are different.  But if there is some relationship, say between [1], y[1] and z[1], then you need to be more considered in your approach.

Thanks @Limey. Fair point. These distributions are uncorrelated. But out of interest, what would be applied if correlated?

Ok.  That's good to know.  Allan's solution is all you need.  If there were some correlation between the variables, then you'd have to model that in your sampling.  How to do so would depend on the nature of that correlation.  One option might be somethig like:  let nx, ny and nz be the length of the three vectors. Generate a random index i.  If i <= nx, sample, x[i], y[i] and z[i].  If nx < i <= ny, sample y[i], z[i] and a random x.  Else sample z[i] and random x' and y`.  But the nature of the correlation would be critical.  Your randomsampling might need to be constrained.

x <- rnorm(n = 2000, mean = 1000, sd = 100)
y <- rnorm(n = 3000, mean = 100, sd = 10)
z <- rnorm(n = 4000, mean = 10, sd = 1)

my_list <- list(x=x,
                y=y,
                z=z)

plot.new()
par(mfrow = c(3, 2))

i <- 0L
for (name in names(my_list)) {
  value <- my_list[[name]]
  i <- i + 1L
  par(mfg = c(i, 1))
 hist(value,main=paste0(name,": ",length(value)))
}


resampled_list <- lapply(my_list,\(s)sample(s,10000,replace=TRUE))

i <- 0L
for (name in names(resampled_list)) {
  value <- resampled_list[[name]]
  i <- i + 1L
  par(mfg = c(i, 2))
  hist(value,main=paste0(name,": ",length(value)))
}



Thanks @Nir Graham. I appreciate your help here - very detailed answer
